# Getting 404 when adding a Symfony bundle generated by openapi-generator

Tags: php, symfony, openapi, openapi-generator

*(This is probably a basic question due to my limited knowledge with both openapi-generator and Symfony, however I've spent a couple of evenings experimenting and reading docs, and I'm still stuck so I'll go ahead and ask)*

**In a nutshell**

I created a Symfony bundle using openapi-generator and I followed the procedure from the generated `README`. After that I can see my routes as expected when I run `./bin/console debug:router`; however I get a `404` page which mentions exceptions `NotFoundHttpException` and `ResourceNotFoundException` when I query my route. I don't understand what could be missing.

**More details on what I did**

I'm using this simple `openapi.yaml` file:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /my-route:
    get:
      summary: placeholder
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
```

I then build my Symfony bundle with:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-6.3.0.jar generate --git-user-id my_name --git-repo-id my_project -i openapi.yaml -g php-symfony -o php-symfony
```

Meanwhile, in another directory, I create a symfony app by following [the doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html):

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton:"6.2.*" my_symfony_app
cd my_symfony_app/
composer require webapp
```

And now I try adding the bundle following the doc in the generated `README` of the bundle:

- In `my_symfony_app/composer.json` I add

```
"repositories": [{
    "type": "path",
    "url": "/path/to/php-symfony"
}],
```

- From `my_symfony_app` I run `composer require my_name/my_project:dev-main` (and select `y` when asked for `Do you want to execute this recipe?`)
- Add in `my_symfony_app/config/routes.yaml` the lines

```
open_api_server:
    resource: "@OpenAPIServerBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

- My file `my_symfony_app/config/bundles.php` already contains the line `OpenAPI\Server\OpenAPIServerBundle::class => ['all' => true],` so I don't have to change it
- Add a `DefaultApiInterface` class as explained in the `README` and registers it in `my_symfony_app/config/services.yaml`

And once all this is done (and after I install this app on my php server), when I query `http://localhost/my_symfony_app/public/index.php/my-route` I get a `404` with that stacktrace

```
in vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php (line 127)
in vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php -> onKernelRequest (line 115)
... removed for conciseness...
in vendor/symfony/runtime/Runner/Symfony/HttpKernelRunner.php -> handle (line 35)
in vendor/autoload_runtime.php -> run (line 29)
```

However when I run `./bin/console debug:router` I get a result which contains that line

```
open_api_server_default_myrouteget   GET      ANY      ANY    /my-route
```

Comment: That route should be `http://localhost/my-route`. Not sure how you have set your local server up, but the doc root should point to the public directory..

Comment: I just copied  `my_symfony_app` to the root of my PHP server; I though it was easy and it should worked since I managed to reach routes I defined on ad hoc controller with this kind of URLs. But I just gave a try to spawning a server with `symfony server:start` and it turns out that `http://localhost:8000/my-route` does indeed find that route, which show that my issue was with installing the app.
Thanks for your comment! :)
(Don't hesitate to turn it into some kind of answer so I can accept it)